# Standard way to load initial (and ongoing) data into Django

Tags: django, django-fixtures

Suppose I have a model with a field that restricts another model.  For example, a `Thing` whose `name` has to be in the current set of `AllowedThingNames`.  The set of allowed_thing_names changes (infrequently) by an external source.  I have code to get that external source and create `AllowedThingNames` as needed.

Here is some code:

**models.py:**

```
class AllowedThingName(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Thing(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __save__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if AllowedThingName.objects.filter(name=self.name).exists():
      return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    return None
```

**tasks.py:**

```
@shared_task
def import_new_names():
  response = request.get("some/external/url/where/allowed/names/are/listed")
  new_names = clever_way_of_parsing_response(response.content)
  for new_name in new_names:
    AllowedThingName.objects.get_or_create(name=new_name)
```

I have created a fixture of `AllowedThingNames` and I run the `loaddata` command at startup.

I'm not sure what the best way is to keep the set of `AllowedThingNames` up-to-date, though.

One solution is to periodically (via a task, or a cronjob, or whatever) call the `import_new_names` function above and then call `dumpdata` to overwrite the fixture.  This will save it in the db and make sure that it gets re-loaded the next time the project restarts.

Does anybody in StackOverflow-Land have any better ideas?

Comment: I am assuming, when you shut down your server, your database resets?

Comment: @ruddra That is not correct. The db is on AWS RDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating a ForeignKey relationship between `Thing` and `AllowedThingName`? Something along the lines of

```
class AllowedThingName(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Thing(models.Model):
  name = models.ForeignKey(AllowedThingName, on_delete=models.CASCASE)
```

Comment: That doesn't quite capture the situation.  `Things` should not be deleted.  They should just be prevented from being _created_ if their name is not in the current set of `AllowedThingNames`.

Comment: The way this would work is every instance of `Thing` HAS to be tied to `AllowedThingName`, otherwise it will not be created. The `on_delete` part only comes into play if an instance of `Thing` is deleted and helps set that behavior. It's fully explained in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)